# How to check for a condition that is never met?

Tags: logic

Taking an example to clarify, say I have a program that takes in two inputs from the user, a and b. The program increments a and decrements b. The program returns the value at which a and b both become equal. Hence, a has to be smaller and b has to be larger. But what if the user enters the opposite? a as larger and b as smaller? The program would go into an infinite loop obviously. But suppose I want the program to return that "these two numbers can never meet". Then how do I check for it? Please don't answer that check for the numbers and respond respectively. This is just an example. I want to know how to check for a condition that can never be met.

Another example, say comparing two numbers. Suppose I have two numbers and I keep randomising them. The program should return true when they are equal and false when they are not. It should not go into an infinite loop when the numbers are not equal. I can only keep comparing the numbers in each iteration and return true as soon as they are equal. But there are likely chances that they never become equal and the program never terminates. How to check for such a scenario and return something like the numbers can never be equal.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  Are you looking for a general-purpose way to check for inputs that would cause your problem to not terminate?  That's the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), for which there is no general solution.

Comment: I think you've pretty much answered your question. *a has to be smaller and b has to be larger.* So if `a` is larger than `b`,  then the condition will never be true and so it will run infinitely.

Comment: The research on the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem continues!

Comment: @RanhiruCooray please go through the question again,I don't want answer to the example I have given

Answer (score 1):

It has to be done on a case-by-case basis; the general problem (given an iterative procedure controlled by a variable condition, determine whether the condition will ever assume a given value, e.g. True) is equivalent to the halting problem, which is uncomputable...

Answer (score -1):

A simple if statement, like this?

```
if (a <= b)
  throw "Condition cannot be met"
else
    for ( ; a != b; a--, b++) {
        // Do something
    }
```

Example in c++

**EDIT** I got A and B the wrong way round! Same scenario though.